# Is the up-voting all comments but one an equivalent of down-voting this very comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, voting

Imagine following situation - somebody has left a comment, which, for some reasons, say, me, don't like at all.

Basically, when I down-vote an answer I want this answer to be lower if answers are sorted by relevance. As we all know, there's no such thing like down-voting a comment. But actually there is way to influence on the probability of "hiding" the unfavourable comment - all we have to do is just to up-vote all the rest comments.

Meta is a dangerous place, so I should state very loud and clear - I find such "hacks" by all means inappropriate, since they increase informational noise. As @RovertHarvey said, "this mess up the ranking of all the other comments". Once again, I'm not claiming this should be done (in fact, I'm strongly against it), but just that it **can** be done.

But question I want to discuss here is - If up-voting all comments except particular one is a logical equivalent (in context of influence on answers ranking) of down-voting such comment, may be we should nevertheless implement comment down-voting?

I'm aware of the fact this had been discussed like dozens time, but never saw this very argument.

Comment: short answer: not really. Although I like your reasoning.

Comment: *"If up-voting all comments except particular one is a logical equivalent of down-voting such comment, may be we should nevertheless implement comment down-voting?"* ... nah, because if what you say is true, we already have a mechanism to achieve the same. :)

Comment: If you do that, you're just going to mess up the ranking of all the other comments.  I don't know the exact algorithm, but comments with no votes are typically hidden if the comment chain is long.  Upvoting comments that shouldn't be upvoted tells the system that they are important and should be displayed, when they actually are not.

Comment: No, it is not - mainly because one comment being not-useful does not mean that the rest are useful. Voting indicates usefulness in main, not agreement or how much you like the person's opinion.

Comment: @RobertHarvey added a couple of sentences to the question to make clear that I actually totally agree with you.

Comment: Does this mean someone wanted to downvote my previous comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, I don't think it is. This divides *all* of the comments into, basically, two comments: all of the good ones together, and the "bad" one. I don't think you should up-vote a bunch of awesome, mediocre, and bad-but-just-not-as-bad-as-that-bad-comment comments to float a bad comment down and treat all of the others as "good" or "important." If the comment is bad (inappropriate) for a specific reason, flag it. If you just don't like what they say, refute it (if it is spreading bad information) or just ignore it.

Comments are not meant to be permanent, and we shouldn't be encouraging such lengthy threads or putting any more serious thought into gaming them.

IMHO.

Regarding your edit, yes, this *can* be done, but so what? Have you seen it happen? To what detrimental effect? Can you cite some actual, real-world examples where people have cheated the sorting in this way, and can demonstrate that there was any bad outcome from this behavior at all? Note also that this sorting is only enforced when there are so many comments that you have to click the link to show more comments - once that link is clicked, all the comments are chronological again, regardless of their score.

Comment: I totally agree with your words about inappropriate bisection of comments, it definitely not something one SHOULD do. All I'm trying to say - somebody CAN do this to cheat the sorting mechanism, which hide comments with less number of votes.

Comment: @shabunc one person applying up-votes to all the comments in a noisy thread is unlikely to really change anything. Do you have any evidence  of this ever happening anywhere? Could you cite an example, or at least predict what problems would result from "cheating" the sorting mechanism? Note also that this sorting is only enforced when there are so many comments that you have to click the link to show more comments - once that link is clicked, all the comments are chronological again, regardless of their score.

Comment: well, just like single answer down-vote does not change anything drastically.

Comment: @shabunc down-voting an answer is very different in a lot of ways: (1) it costs the voter and the author reputation (2) an answer is a much more important part of the ecosystem than a comment. Again, yes, one person could, if they wanted to, and if they really thought it would do any good for anyone, up-vote all the other comments in a thread. Do I think it's likely to happen? No. In the event that it does happen, do I think it will change anything about anyone's experience on that page? No.

Comment: Bertand I believe that those are very valid points. I believe   it would be better to incorporate them to the answer, and I'll accept it. You know, comments are less important part of the ecosystem ;)

Comment: oh, my bad, sorry for typo in your name, no offence (